# Images Not Loading from URL

Tags: android, rss, picasso

I am trying to load some images into a list view using Picasso but I'm only seeing my placeholder image. I'm loading the data from an RSS feed and can confirm that everything works correctly with my old feed URL. The only difference between the two is that the image URL is formatted differently. I'm getting the URLs but my placeholder image never gets replaced by the image from the URL.

In my fragment:

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("enclosure");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element thumbElement = (Element)nodes.item(i);
                String thumbURL = thumbElement.getAttribute("url");
                if (thumbURL.equals("")) {
                    thumb[i] = "null";
                } else {
                    thumb[i] = thumbURL;
                }
            }
```

In my adapter:

```
if (ActionAlertsFragment.thumb[position] != "null") {
            System.out.println(ActionAlertsFragment.thumb[position]);
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(ActionAlertsFragment.thumb[position])
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(holder.thumbnail);
        } else {
            holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
        }
```

One of the image URLs from the new feed:
http://www.kyfb.com/index.cfm/_api/render/file/?fileID=38C277EC-9B70-510A-DE9D93916BAF084C&fileEXT=.jpg

Image URL from the old feed:
http://kyfbnewsroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/250px-KY_State_Capitol.jpg

Old feed that works:
http://kyfbnewsroom.com/category/public-affairs/notifications/feed/

New feed that doesn't load images:
https://www.kyfb.com/index.cfm/_api/feed/v1/KYFB/?feedID=61433D1B-DAB1-6572-3CD3CBF8A0142B4B

I'm starting to think that the images don't get loaded from the new URLs because the image URLs are formatted differently and can't be loaded correctly for some reason. the image URLs from the old feed work as expected.

Comment: did you added network permission in manifest.xml?

Comment: Yes. I get all other data from the RSS feed just fine and if I use an older version of this feed with a different URL, everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing this by replacing "http" in every URL with "https"

Comment: This was the solution for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a problem here

```
if (ActionAlertsFragment.thumb[position] != "null") {
```

just use the "equals" function and i think it will work

```
if (!ActionAlertsFragment.thumb[position].equals("null")) {
```